# Count number of occurrences of vector in list

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors of variable length, for example:

```
q <- list(c(1,3,5), c(2,4), c(1,3,5), c(2,5), c(7), c(2,5))
```

I need to count the number of occurrences for each of the vectors in the list, for example (any other suitable datastructure acceptable):

```
list(list(c(1,3,5), 2), list(c(2,4), 1), list(c(2,5), 2), list(c(7), 1))
```

Is there an efficient way to do this? The actual list has tens of thousands of items so quadratic behaviour is not feasible.

Comment: You could use a hash function, and then have the desired list per hash, which greatly reduces the average complexity.

Comment: `match` and `unique` work on "list"s too -- `match(q, unique(q))` and then tabulate the occurences

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`match` and `unique` accept and handle "list"s too (`?match` warns for being slow on "list"s). So, with:

```
match(q, unique(q))
#[1] 1 2 1 3 4 3
```

each element is mapped to a single integer. Then:

```
tabulate(match(q, unique(q)))
#[1] 2 1 2 1
```

And find a structure to present the results:

```
as.data.frame(cbind(vec = unique(q), n = tabulate(match(q, unique(q)))))
#      vec n
#1 1, 3, 5 2
#2    2, 4 1
#3    2, 5 2
#4       7 1
```

Alternatively to `match(x, unique(x))` approach, we could map each element to a single value with `deparse`ing:

```
table(sapply(q, deparse))
#
#         7 c(1, 3, 5)    c(2, 4)    c(2, 5) 
#         1          2          1          2
```

Also, since this is a case with unique integers, and assuming in a small range, we could map each element to a single integer after transforming each element to a binary representation:

```
n = max(unlist(q))
pow2 = 2 ^ (0:(n - 1))
sapply(q, function(x) tabulate(x, nbins = n))  # 'binary' form
sapply(q, function(x) sum(tabulate(x, nbins = n) * pow2))
#[1] 21 10 21 18 64 18
```

and then `tabulate` as before.

And just to compare the above alternatives:

```
f1 = function(x) 
{
    ux = unique(x)
    i = match(x, ux)
    cbind(vec = ux, n = tabulate(i))
}   

f2 = function(x)
{
    xc = sapply(x, deparse)
    i = match(xc, unique(xc))
    cbind(vec = x[!duplicated(i)], n = tabulate(i))
}  

f3 = function(x)
{
    n = max(unlist(x))
    pow2 = 2 ^ (0:(n - 1))
    v = sapply(x, function(X) sum(tabulate(X, nbins = n) * pow2))
    i = match(v, unique(v))
    cbind(vec = x[!duplicated(v)], n = tabulate(i))
}

q2 = rep_len(q, 1e3)

all.equal(f1(q2), f2(q2))
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(f2(q2), f3(q2))
#[1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(q2), f2(q2), f3(q2))
#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
# f1(q2)  7.980041  8.161524 10.525946  8.291678  8.848133 178.96333   100  b 
# f2(q2) 24.407143 24.964991 27.311056 25.514834 27.538643  45.25388   100   c
# f3(q2)  3.951567  4.127482  4.688778  4.261985  4.518463  10.25980   100 a
```

Another interesting alternative is based on ordering. R > 3.3.0 has a `grouping` function, built off data.table, which, along with the ordering, provides some attributes for further manipulation:

Make all elements of equal length and "transpose" (probably the most slow operation in this case, though I'm not sure how else to feed `grouping`):

```
n = max(lengths(q))
qq = .mapply(c, lapply(q, "[", seq_len(n)), NULL)
```

Use ordering to group similar elements mapped to integers:

```
gr = do.call(grouping, qq)
e = attr(gr, "ends") 
i = rep(seq_along(e), c(e[1], diff(e)))[order(gr)]
i
#[1] 1 2 1 3 4 3
```

then, tabulate as before.
To continue the comparisons:

```
f4 = function(x)
{
    n = max(lengths(x))
    x2 = .mapply(c, lapply(x, "[", seq_len(n)), NULL)
    gr = do.call(grouping, x2)
    e = attr(gr, "ends") 
    i = rep(seq_along(e), c(e[1], diff(e)))[order(gr)]
    cbind(vec = x[!duplicated(i)], n = tabulate(i))
}

all.equal(f3(q2), f4(q2))
#[1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(q2), f2(q2), f3(q2), f4(q2))
#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval cld
# f1(q2)  7.956377  8.048250  8.792181  8.131771  8.270101  21.944331   100  b 
# f2(q2) 24.228966 24.618728 28.043548 25.031807 26.188219 195.456203   100   c
# f3(q2)  3.963746  4.103295  4.801138  4.179508  4.360991  35.105431   100 a  
# f4(q2)  2.874151  2.985512  3.219568  3.066248  3.186657   7.763236   100 a
```

In this comparison `q`'s elements are of small length to accomodate for `f3`, but `f3` (because of large exponentiation) and `f4` (because of `mapply`) will suffer, in performance, if "list"s of larger elements are used.

Answer (score 7):

One way is to paste each vector , unlist and tabulate, i.e.

```
table(unlist(lapply(q, paste, collapse = ',')))

#1,3,5   2,4   2,5     7 
#    2     1     2     1
```

Comment: Nice alternative - you could also use `sapply` instead of `lapply` + `unlist`, i.e. `table(sapply(q, paste, collapse = ","))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus true. I always go to `lapply` without meaning it  when I see lists...